# A simplest scalafx example can't be compiled

Tags: scala, javafx, scalafx

I'm trying the scalafx with a simplest example, but it can't be compiled and the error is like:

> Error:scalac: bad symbolic reference to javafx.stage.PopupWindow.AnchorLocation encountered in class file 'StageIncludes.class'.
>   Cannot access type AnchorLocation in object javafx.stage.PopupWindow. The current classpath may be
>   missing a definition for javafx.stage.PopupWindow.AnchorLocation, or StageIncludes.class may have been compiled against a version that's
>   incompatible with the one found on the current classpath.

I googled and found someone say we need to add the `jfxrt.jar` to classpath, but which is still not working.

My code:

**build.sbt**

```
name := "ColaBlog"

version := "0.1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.0"

libraryDependencies ++= List(
  "org.scalafx" % "scalafx_2.11" % "8.0.0-R4"
)

unmanagedJars in Compile += Attributed.blank(
  file(scala.util.Properties.javaHome) / "lib" / "jfxrt.jar")

fork in run := true
```

**App.scala**

```
import scalafx.Includes._
import scalafx.application.JFXApp
import scalafx.scene.Scene
import scalafx.scene.paint.Color
import scalafx.scene.shape.Rectangle

object App extends JFXApp {

  stage = new JFXApp.PrimaryStage {
    title = "Hello World"
    width = 600
    height = 450
    scene = new Scene {
      fill = Color.LIGHTGREEN
      content = Set(new Rectangle {
        x = 25
        y = 40
        width = 100
        height = 100
        fill <== when(hover) choose Color.GREEN otherwise Color.RED
      })
    }
  }
}
```

That's all.

Comment: What version of Java/JavaFX? From the API there seems to be no PopupWindow.AnchorLocation in Fx2.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works correctly on the Java 8 JVM. The likely problem is that you are running on a Java 7 install.

By these [release notes](https://code.google.com/p/scalafx/wiki/ReleaseHistory) ScalaFX has two parallel releases:

- v.1.0.0 - supports JavaFX 2 and Java 7 (SFX-1)
- v.8.0.0 - supports JavaFX 8 and Java 8 (SFX-8)

Either update Java, or use the other release.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a little dated, but downloading from:

https://jdk8.java.net/download.html

worked for me.

Make sure to change your project settings to use this JDK.