# SBT won't compile HelloWorld ScalaFX example, complains about javafx missing from the classpath

Tags: java, scala, javafx, sbt, scalafx

I am new to Scala, and have never used a build tool before, and I am having some trouble getting the HelloWorld example on the [scalafx quickstart page](http://www.scalafx.org/docs/quickstart/) to compile.

I previously tried to use the [scala IDE 4.7.0 Release](http://scala-ide.org/) to run the code, by creating a new scala project, and adding the [scalafx.jar version 8.0.102-R11](https://search.maven.org/search?q=a:scalafx_2.12.0-RC2) as an external jar in the build path libraries' option. However, when I right clicked on the project and selected "Run as", there was no option to run it as a Scala Application, and trying to use the object name in a new run configuration didn't seem to work. I decided to try using the command line with SBT instead.

I am running Windows 10, and I have Java 8 installed, as well as JDK 12.0.2. I have created a project in my downloads folder, inside a folder called scalahelloworld, and ran the following command:

> sbt new scala/hello-world.g8

This created the hello world project normally, and it compiles and runs without issues. However, when I tried following the instructions on the quick start guide for scalafx, adding the line

> libraryDependencies += "org.scalafx" %% "scalafx" % "8.0.144-R12"

to build.sbt, and well as using their example code in my main object, it gives me some compiling errors:

```
C:\Users\hugo.barroca\Downloads\SBT Project\scalahelloworld>sbt
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0
[info] Loading project definition from C:\Users\hugo.barroca\Downloads\SBT Project\scalahelloworld\project
[info] Loading settings for project scalahelloworld from build.sbt ...
[info] Set current project to hello-world (in build file:/C:/Users/hugo.barroca/Downloads/SBT%20Project/scalahelloworld/)
[info] sbt server started at local:sbt-server-3c8f646db648b9d2b646
sbt:hello-world> compile
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to C:\Users\hugo.barroca\Downloads\SBT Project\scalahelloworld\target\scala-2.12\classes ...
[error] C:\Users\hugo.barroca\Downloads\SBT Project\scalahelloworld\src\main\scala\Main.scala:15:3: Symbol 'type javafx.event.EventTarget' is missing from the classpath.
[error] This symbol is required by 'class scalafx.stage.Window'.
[error] Make sure that type EventTarget is in your classpath and check for conflicting dependencies with `-Ylog-classpath`.
[error] A full rebuild may help if 'Window.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of javafx.event.
[error]   stage = new PrimaryStage {
[error]   ^
[error] C:\Users\hugo.barroca\Downloads\SBT Project\scalahelloworld\src\main\scala\Main.scala:17:17: Symbol 'term javafx.css' is missing from the classpath.
[error] This symbol is required by 'trait scalafx.css.Styleable'.
[error] Make sure that term css is in your classpath and check for conflicting dependencies with `-Ylog-classpath`.
[error] A full rebuild may help if 'Styleable.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of javafx.
[error]     scene = new Scene {
[error]                 ^
[error] C:\Users\hugo.barroca\Downloads\SBT Project\scalahelloworld\src\main\scala\Main.scala:17:5: Symbol 'type javafx.scene.Scene' is missing from the classpath.
[error] This symbol is required by 'class scalafx.scene.Scene'.
[error] Make sure that type Scene is in your classpath and check for conflicting dependencies with `-Ylog-classpath`.
[error] A full rebuild may help if 'Scene.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of javafx.scene.
[error]     scene = new Scene {
[error]     ^
[error] C:\Users\hugo.barroca\Downloads\SBT Project\scalahelloworld\src\main\scala\Main.scala:22:15: Symbol 'type javafx.scene.text.Text' is missing from the classpath.
[error] This symbol is required by 'class scalafx.scene.text.Text'.
[error] Make sure that type Text is in your classpath and check for conflicting dependencies with `-Ylog-classpath`.
[error] A full rebuild may help if 'Text.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of javafx.scene.text.
[error]           new Text {
[error]               ^
[error] C:\Users\hugo.barroca\Downloads\SBT Project\scalahelloworld\src\main\scala\Main.scala:25:24: Symbol 'term javafx.scene.paint' is missing from the classpath.
[error] This symbol is required by 'class scalafx.scene.paint.LinearGradient'.
[error] Make sure that term paint is in your classpath and check for conflicting dependencies with `-Ylog-classpath`.
[error] A full rebuild may help if 'LinearGradient.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of javafx.scene.
[error]             fill = new LinearGradient(
[error]                        ^
[error] C:\Users\hugo.barroca\Downloads\SBT Project\scalahelloworld\src\main\scala\Main.scala:36:26: Symbol 'type javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow' is missing from the classpath.
[error] This symbol is required by 'class scalafx.scene.effect.DropShadow'.
[error] Make sure that type DropShadow is in your classpath and check for conflicting dependencies with `-Ylog-classpath`.
[error] A full rebuild may help if 'DropShadow.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of javafx.scene.effect.
[error]             effect = new DropShadow {
[error]                          ^
[error] 6 errors found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
sbt:hello-world[error] Total time: 4 s, completed 23/08/2019, 13:19:55
>
sbt:hello-world>
```

I have come across some SO pages which led me to believe the problem might be [either with my version of Java or JDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23447259/a-simplest-scalafx-example-cant-be-compiled), or with the classpath. However, I haven't been able to solve it so far. I have tried reinstalling Java, the JDK, STB and tried different versions of the ScalaFX jar, in particular version 8.0.12. I have also tried installing openjfx following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28543688/scalafx-helloworld-compilation-error). So far there's been no changes.

The only code I have is that of the example file:

```
package hello

import scalafx.application.JFXApp
import scalafx.application.JFXApp.PrimaryStage
import scalafx.geometry.Insets
import scalafx.scene.Scene
import scalafx.scene.effect.DropShadow
import scalafx.scene.layout.HBox
import scalafx.scene.paint.Color._
import scalafx.scene.paint.{Stops, LinearGradient}
import scalafx.scene.text.Text

object Main extends JFXApp {

  stage = new PrimaryStage {
    title = "ScalaFX Hello World"
    scene = new Scene {
      fill = Black
      content = new HBox {
        padding = Insets(20)
        children = Seq(
          new Text {
            text = "Hello "
            style = "-fx-font-size: 48pt"
            fill = new LinearGradient(
              endX = 0,
              stops = Stops(PaleGreen, SeaGreen))
          },
          new Text {
            text = "World!!!"
            style = "-fx-font-size: 48pt"
            fill = new LinearGradient(
              endX = 0,
              stops = Stops(Cyan, DodgerBlue)
            )
            effect = new DropShadow {
              color = DodgerBlue
              radius = 25
              spread = 0.25
            }
          }
        )
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How would I go about solving this particular issue, so that the code compiles properly and displays the HelloWorld scalafx window?

Comment: From Java 11, JavaFX is no longer shipped with JDK. You need to download separate jar file for it, and Scala dependency doesn't cover that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit of digging shows that you most likely need to add a OS-specific dependency for the JavaFX binaries. Add the following to the bottom of your `build.sbt`

```
lazy val osName = System.getProperty("os.name") match {
  case n if n.startsWith("Linux") => "linux"
  case n if n.startsWith("Mac") => "mac"
  case n if n.startsWith("Windows") => "win"
  case _ => throw new Exception("Unknown platform!")
}

// Add JavaFX dependencies
lazy val javaFXModules = Seq("base", "controls", "fxml", "graphics", "media", "swing", "web")
libraryDependencies ++= javaFXModules.map( m=>
  "org.openjfx" % s"javafx-$m" % "11" classifier osName
)
```

As they do in the example project: https://github.com/scalafx/scalafx-hello-world/blob/master/build.sbt

It can also be an issue with some of the JDK distrubutions, such as the OpenJDK distribution on Ubuntu. If I recall right there are two different ways to solve it. One is to add JavaFX to your dependencies:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.openjfx" % "javafx" % "12.0.2" pomOnly()
```

If I remember right this is probably the nicest way to do it. Should that work add it through your package manager, in Ubuntu that would be:

```sh
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk openjfx
```

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1091157/javafx-missing-ubuntu-18-04 might be useful.

Also as the askubuntu points out, you probably want to make sure you set it to run using Java 8 for your projects.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunatly that didn't resolve my issue. I tried adding it as a dependency and the error stayed the same, although it updated the project and downloaded the new dependency sucessfully. Also, I am running on windows, and downloaded the JDK from the official oracle site. The only folders I have in my Program Files/Java folder are one for jdk-12.0.2 and one for jre1.8.0_221, which I think are the correct ones as they're the latest available on the website.

Comment: Can you check the Java used in the IDE? I know on Linux it's sometimes easier to just have two versions and point IntelliJ to Java 8. I suspect the same could be the case for you then :)

Comment: I'm actually using the windows command prompt to run SBT right now, as at first I feared the problem might have been some configuration issue with eclipse and so I swiched. I tried checking the java version through the sbt prompt, and it actually returned an error:

sbt:hello-world> eval System.getProperty("java.version")
error: error while loading String, class file '/modules/java.base/java/lang/String.class' is broken
(class java.lang.NullPointerException/null)
[info] ans: String = 12.0.2

Comment: I digged a bit more. I found that they do some additional dependency management in the example project on github. The answer above have been updated with the solution. It worked on my system, so hopefully it will work on a Windows machine too :)

Comment: Thank you! It seems to be working now, the error is gone and the window shows up perfectly!